# Ionic CLI 3: ionic cordova resources - any chance to avoid login

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Today I upgrade `ionic` from 2.2.1 into 3.19.0 version. I was really surprise that they replace command `ionic resources add/rm` with `ionic cordova resources`

-> going this way I was shocked that they required having account on [dashboard.ionicjs.com](https://dashboard.ionicjs.com/login)

Is any chance to avoid this - using this command without login process? Any body maybe know the reason way they provide it now this way?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this is Wrong

> I upgrade ionic from 2.2.1 into 3.19.0 version

**Why?** It is not ionic. It was `Ionic CLI`. The current `Ionic` version is [**3.9.2**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v3.9.2)

> Is any chance to avoid this - using this command without login
>   process?

You **can't do that**. Because `ionic cordova resources` is required to use **Ionic team's cloud servers** to do that job. So they identify and log your details through your login information.

Comment: My bad you have right - this was `ionic-cli` version. But still question remains open - maybe there is a way from addons or somethings else.